# Issue while passing locator as a Variable to find_elements method in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am preparing a test automation suite Using Selenium-Python and encountered an issue. I am trying to get a list of web elements using the find elements method.

```
**Method 1:** elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"<My XPATH>") 

-> This is working fine and returns the elements correctly

**Method 2: **
locator = By.XPATH, "<My XPATH>"
elements = driver.find_elements(locator)

This is preferred method based on the POM model and code reusability. But this returns an error as follows
```

ERROR:root:Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
(Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.107)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and see here on [How to format the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this way:

```py
locator = By.XPATH, "<My XPATH>"
elements = driver.find_elements(*locator)
```

so that you unpack your tuple to argument list.